# Passing a value(string) form razor model to JS with onclick attribut

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, model-view-controller

This is my html

```
@model MarketingPhoneBook.Models.Responses.ContactLogResponse
@{
    Layout = "";
}
<form method="post" id="idForm" action="/Home/CreateLog">
    <div class="form-group">
        @{
            var mystring = Html.Raw(Model.NewLog.CallLogText);
        }
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewLog.CallLogText, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label " })
        <div onclick="addDate('@mystring')">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.NewLog.CallLogText, new { @class = "", @style = "width: 100%; max-width: inherit;", @rows = "15", @onblur = "save()", @type = "submit" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewLog.CallLogText, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.NewLog.ContactId)

</form>
```

and this is my js function

```
function addDate(text) {
    return text = new Date() + " " + text;
}
```

Model.NewLog.CallLogText is of type string. Onclick event does not get triggered

Comment: And where is connection between your js and view? (I mean how you have added you js to view)

Comment: Have you checked if the html is correctly rendered? Do you get any errors in your developer tools?

Comment: @SeM In my layout page. Function gets called if i just but a raw string, for example addDate("whatever").

Comment: @Jerodev Onclick i get Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token.

Comment: What's value of you `mystring`? Probably there is some `'` or new line characters inside you string.

Comment: Please show an example of the rendered html

Comment: @SeM There is new line character in my string. Is there a way to get it anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.javascriptstringencode?view=netframework-4.7.2) to encode string before passing to JS:

```
@{
    var mystring = Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Model.NewLog.CallLogText));
}
```